How to run gpu-resources only on the GPU nodepool in AKS
AKS cluster set-up: The cluster is created with Azure CNI overlay and has two node pools, one for the application and another for networking. The networking node pool just has two CPU VMs. The application node pool uses GPU VMs.
When enabling the gpu-resources daemon set on the cluster using the steps outlined for Azure AKS here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/gpu-cluster?tabs=add-ubuntu-gpu-node-pool#manually-install-the-nvidia-device-plugin
is there a way to restrict the pods to run only on the GPU node pool?
The node pool has the taint sku=gpu:NoSchedule and the gpu-resources deployment has this specified:
    spec:
      tolerations:
      # Allow this pod to be rescheduled while the node is in "critical add-ons only" mode.
      # This, along with the annotation above marks this pod as a critical add-on.
      - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
        operator: Exists
      - key: nvidia.com/gpu
        operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      - key: "sku"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "gpu"
        effect: "NoSchedule"

but still pods get scheduled on the networking pool VMs and I see this:
kubectl get pods -n gpu-resources
NAME                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-7dr7n   1/1     Running            0             11m
nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-9nzbv   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (48s ago)   11m
nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-hbck6   1/1     Running            0             11m
nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-hksv9   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (48s ago)   11m
nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-kp74v   1/1     Running            0             11m

with the CrashLoopBackOff happening on the two CPU VMs in the networking node pool.
Is there a way to run these pods only on the GPU node pool?

Arun have you tried using node selectors in addition to the taints/tolerations you've used? `spec:
nodeSelector:
nodepool: gpunp
tolerations:

key: CriticalAddonsOnly
operator: Exists
key: nvidia.com/gpu
operator: Exists
effect: NoSchedule
key: "sku"
operator: "Equal"
value: "gpu"
effect: "NoSchedule"`


Taking hint from @Arko's comment under the question, one way to solve this is using node affinity as outlined here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-advanced-scheduler#node-affinity
I applied the label hardware:gpu to the application node pool and used it in the deployment YAML like this:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: hardware
            operator: In
            values:
            - gpu

